# How to store file contents in a map where a key maps to a data structure with two attributes

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have the file named `abc.txt` in my c: drive which I am reading through java buffered writer approach. Below the content of the file is shown

```
abc.txt
******    
Id|ytr|yts
1|W|T
2|W|T
3|W|T
```

Now I want to store its contents in a collection (that is in a hashmap) in such a way, that for Id key I should get the values of ytr and yts column.

That is for the Id `1` I should get the value of ytr and yts column.

Please advise how can I store such thing in map and retrieve it, I want to achieve it through java itself.

Comment: You can start here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score 1):

Create some sort of class that has ytr and yts as fields. Create a map with id as key (it's an integer, right?) and instances of your new class as the values.

Comment: I have to directly read file and then store it contents into the map

Comment: Right. So do that. Read a line, parse the line, store the contents of said line into a map.

Answer (score -1):

1st of all you should read the file with a reader (not a writer as your question suggests). Any `Reader` which can read a file line by line as a String would do fine. Have a look at `BufferedReader` for example.

Two store the data in a Map you want to map your Key (a simple String, or maybe an Integer) to your data (looks like two Strings).
Since your data is a "complex" data structure, that is there is no primitive data type for it. You should create a class which holds this data as member variables. When you read a line, you then create an instance of that class, assign the data to this object and put it in your `HashMap` with the key. Look at the put method which accepts a key and a value object.

I am sure, the rest you can figure out on your own. Please have a look at the JavaDoc of the classes I mentioned here. If you have some basic understanding of what a class / object is, you can accomplish the rest.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please explain what is wrong with that post. I am too happy to improve my answer if there is anything wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

Use following example.

### Content of File:

```
1 W T 
2 W T 
3 W T
```

### Program for loading and viewing input file content

```
    Map<Integer,String[]> map=new HashMap<>();
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String[] str=sc.nextLine().split(" +");
        //Store to map.
        map.put(Integer.valueOf(str[0]), new String[]{str[1],str[2]});
    }
    //Get key and values from map
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,String[]> entry: map.entrySet()){
        System.out.print("Key : "+ entry.getKey() +" Values : [");
        for (String str : entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.print(" "+str);
        }
        System.out.println(" ]");
    }
```

Comment: Don't like the answer. Too many assumptions, no explanation but complete sourcecode for a beginners question -1 from me.